# how can i Automate documentation in my CI/CD pipeline or through my project workflow (java) ? documentation generator for the whole process?

Tags: automation, markdown, generator, documentation, documentation-generation

Currently i am writting the documentation of my project Manually , it's hard and time consuming i want a solution that help me to generate documentation automatically is there any plugins or tools or solution to automate the documentation in each phase of the project from installation and configuration to the deployment. (Java Project , Terraform File and Jenkins File )

i used a javadoc for the development phase and terraform-docs when it comes to infrastructure documentation.
also i tried to use a Markdown Template with variable but it's not practical and doesn't solve my issue.

YET i am not looking only for the API documentation , i want to have a markdown files for each team in git where i can find a simple and easy to read full description documentation